# How to filter object entries to keep only those whose keys start with a string, using ramda?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Having the following array:

```js
const vegsAndFruits = [
    {
        "fruit_banana": 10,
        "fruit_apple": 1,
        "veg_tomato": 3,
        "fruit_watermelon": 11
    },
    {
        "veg_carrot": 3,
        "veg_garlic": 11,
        "veg_potato": 0,
        "fruit_apricot": 22
    },
    {
        "veg_eggplant": 2,
        "veg_cabbage": 1,
        "fruit_strawberry": 100,
        "fruit_orange": 30
    }
]
```

I want to filter it to return the same array **but** to keep only the properties that start with `"fruit"`.

*Expected output*

```js
const expectedOutput = [
    {
        "fruit_banana": 10,
        "fruit_apple": 1,
        "fruit_watermelon": 11
    },
    {
        "fruit_apricot": 22
    },
    {
        "fruit_strawberry": 100,
        "fruit_orange": 30
    }
]
```

*My attempt*

I thought the solution should come from mixing ramda's `R.startsWith()` and `R.pickBy()`. But the following doesn't work as I expected:

```js
const R = require("ramda")

R.map(R.pickBy(R.startsWith(["fruit"])),vegsAndFruits)
```

which returns

```js
// [ {}, {}, {} ]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `R.pickBy` predicate is called with the `value` (1st) and `key` (2nd) parameters. Since you need the `key`, use `R.nthArg` to create a function that returns the 2nd param:

```js
const { map, pickBy, pipe, nthArg, startsWith } = R

const fn = map(pickBy(pipe(
  nthArg(1),
  startsWith('fruit')
)))

const vegsAndFruits = [{"fruit_banana":10,"fruit_apple":1,"veg_tomato":3,"fruit_watermelon":11},{"veg_carrot":3,"veg_garlic":11,"veg_potato":0,"fruit_apricot":22},{"veg_eggplant":2,"veg_cabbage":1,"fruit_strawberry":100,"fruit_orange":30}]

const result = fn(vegsAndFruits)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Just one note: it should be `const result = fn(vegsAndFruits)` rather than `const result = fn(expectedOutput)`.

Comment: Updated. You've got multiple questions on which you haven't accept any answers. Go over them and accept the answer that fits you most.

Answer (score 2):

The pickby function takes two parameters, value and key.

You can run `R.map(R.pickBy((_, key) => key.startsWith('fruit')),vegsAndFruits)` to get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is very nice. Could you explain the part of `(_, key)`? How does the `_` work?

Comment: in Ramda, _ is a placeholder for generic data in curried functions. The pickby function takes arguments for the value and key of an object, and in this case the value is not being searched, so it is set to the default placeholder. You can get the same result by replacing '_' with anything. For example you could run the same function to search if the value starts with fruit by writing `R.map(R.pickBy((value, _) => value.startsWith('fruit')),vegsAndFruits)`